# How to reload changes / HotSwap reload classes without IDE

Tags: java, gradle, hotswap, dcevm, hotswapagent

Currently my setup consists of vim and a separate terminal window running Gradle tasks.

I want to know if its possible to trigger a reload / recompile changes classes actions for a Gradle daemon so that DCEVM can detect them and reload them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HotswapAgent and autoHotswap=true, look at http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_configuration.html.